# center a triangle

Tags: css

I have triangles where i want to cemter

Comment: Consider posting your code to the public, e.g. using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: for some reason it is not working, i got triangles from google btw for the image.

Comment: `Top right corner of triangle overlaps triangle 2`: what do you mean? Nothing's overlapping in your demo, and your triangles don't have any top right corners.

Comment: sorry, i meant bottom right of triangle 1, ill edit that

Comment: ive edit my question, if i was to put it into a table, would that be much easier? So if I can center the image and have it overlapping in the table?

Comment: What do you mean `overlaps triangle 2`? Do you *want* it to overlap, because right now it isn't. And there's no need for a table for centering. See my answer.

Comment: using z-index: will make it overlap

Comment: overlap like this - http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?q=two+triangles+overlap&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&biw=1366&bih=639&tbm=isch&tbnid=DetxzaJnDWDSIM:&imgrefurl=http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/discussions/VennDiagramBeginner/&docid=PKU7MmU5L9dMeM&imgurl=http://www.shodor.org/media/N/G/I/zNmE2MDc2NTlmOTVlNDA2YzVmMmE5ZGYxMmJiMzI.jpg&w=601&h=296&ei=4XxoT-TBB8bL0QWWtsHzCA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=89&vpy=280&dur=889&hovh=157&hovw=320&tx=214&ty=68&sig=118173414403133433450&page=3&tbnh=88&tbnw=178&start=43&ndsp=26&ved=1t:429,r:19,s:43 - but with triangles

Comment: Can you create an image of your desired result? Because this is a little confusing.

Comment: I could do but then I would have 1 image and I still want it center on every page using margain-left:auto and margain-right:auto?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this without tables that'll work on all screen sizes. The first way, that I'd recommend (as it doesn't use absolute positions):

```
body {
text-align:center;
}

#div1 {
width: your width;
margin:auto;
}
```

...and same for `div2`. The second way uses absolute positioning, and you'd need to know the width of your divs (which must be fixed). In your example it's 200 px, so accordingly:

```
#div1 {
position: absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-100px; /* half of your width */
}
```

There's nothing to add here for `body`.

Answer (score 0):

You can center with `margin:0 auto;` but note, that a width needs to be specified for this to work. (Which normally is the case for images). Also this only centers horizontally, not vertically.

Also you can center with absolute position, the code would look like this:

```
centeredelement{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   height:<your-height>;
   width:<your-width>;
   margin-left: -<your-width>/2;
   margin-top:  -<your-height>/2;
}
```

note:
unless you are using html5 and it's according doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

your ids starting with a number are invalid (your jsfiddle)!

Answer (score 0):

First off, CSS ID's can't start with a number so your IDs CSS properties are not being picked up. Second you already have a width to work width so you don't need to position your images absolutely to center them. All you have to do is supply a margin of `0 auto` to center them automatically, like so:

```
#a, #b{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xndHu/2/)

Comment: I need them side by side and bottom right corner of 1 to overlap triangle 2

Comment: @LandY With a proper container to center both images, you can have that effect using negative margins, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/xndHu/3/  .. please note that your images have a large white border so you can't see the tip touching, i suggest you use transparent pngs instead.